# 1:N table. Select case depending on multiple different values in N table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, `Order` and `OrderDetail`, with a 1:N relation. The `OrderDetail` table has a `Category` column.

When I select from the `Order` table, I want to select one column with a `CASE` statement. If all `OrderDetail` column's category is food, I want select it as "Food". But if there are many different categories in `OrderDetail` table, I want select it as "Mixed". There are many kinds of category.

So if an order only includes book/food/etc, I want it select as it is. Otherwise, mixed.

I only know basics of SQL. So I was looking for a way to accomplish this. I guess I need subquery but I could not write query at all.

Comment: Just add some sample data with category that you want to display...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query and count the number of different categories and if there is only one category then display that else display `Mixed` (assuming that you have a primary key column in the `orders` table, such as `id`, and a foreign key column in the `order_details` table, such as `order_id`, that references the previous primary key):

```sql
SELECT o.*,
       ( SELECT CASE COUNT(DISTINCT category)
                WHEN 1
                THEN MAX(category)
                ELSE 'Mixed'
                END
         FROM   order_details d
         WHERE  o.id = d.order_id ) AS category
FROM   orders o;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'order1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'order2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'order3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'order4' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE order_details (id, order_id, category) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'Food' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 'Food' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, 'Book' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3, 'Book' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 3, 'Book' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 4, 'Food' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 4, 'Book' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | NAME | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | order1 | Food |
| 2 | order2 | Mixed |
| 3 | order3 | Book |
| 4 | order4 | Mixed |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bEl6VTEQ)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Using MAX in that way is brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 case 
   when not exists (select 1
     from order_details d where m.order_id=d.order_id
     and d.category!='Food') then 'Food' --- there is no row having other cathegory than Food
   else 'Mixed'
  end
 ,m.*
from orders m;
```

Or, it could be:

```
with ord_categs (
  select order_id, category, count(distinct category) cnt_categ
    ,row_number() over (partition by order_id order by category) rn
  from order_details
  group by order_id, category
)
select 
  m.*
  ,case
    when coalesce(c.cnt_categ,1)=1 then c.category --- null if no details exist
    else 'Mixed'
  end
from orders m
left join ord_categs c on m.order_id=c.order_id and 1=rn;
```

Comment: So if there are like 300 categories, I need a lot of case statment? is there any better way?